# I want to add, update and delete the xml from a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, gridview

how to manipulate xml file with the help of gridview.I am unable to convert the gridview into add,update and delete operations and process them.
`enter code here`[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Me0Fb.png

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("d:/myXml.xml");//Adding an element
        [enter image description here][1]
                    SerDes obj = new SerDes();

                    var cat = obj.DeSerialize(xmlDoc.ToString());
                    List<Item> items = cat.Items.ToList();
                    items.Add(new Item { ItemID = 2, ItemName = "Test", ItemPrice = 100, ItemQtyInStock = 50 });// adding an item
                    //cat.Items.ToList().FirstOrDefault(item => item.ItemID == 2).ItemName = "Custom Name"; //updating an item
                    var x = cat.Items.ToList().FirstOrDefault(item => item.ItemID == 2); //deleting an item
                    items.Remove(x);

                    var len = items.Count();
                    cat.Items = items.ToArray();
                    XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
                    xdoc.LoadXml(obj.Serialization(cat));
                    xdoc.Save(@"D:\myXml.xml");
                }

                protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
                    dataSet.ReadXml(@"D:\myXml.xml");
                    GridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[2];
                    GridView1.DataBind();
                }
```

Comment: ok, what is the question ? what is the error ?

Comment: I am unable to bind the add, update and delete operations into the gridview and reflect the changes into the xml file.

Comment: look for tutorials, and then if you have some point that you can not continue come and for - as it is is not a question but a request to build it for you.

Comment: for example : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18280/Edit-XML-files-using-a-GridView

Comment: You may be having a refresh issue with your control.  Changing the DataSource will not automatically refresh the control.  So the trick is to GridView1.DataSource = null;l then  GridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[2];